# Не работает yii2 плагин kartik-DepDrop;

Tags: php, yii2

Установил плагин, добавил поля в вьюшку

```
    <?= $form->field($model, 'category')->dropDownList(\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(
    $categories,
    'name',
    'name'
), ['prompt'=>'Выберите категорию публикации']); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'category_type')->widget(DepDrop::classname(), [
'options' => ['id'=>'subcat-id'],
'pluginOptions'=>[
'depends'=>['publication-category'],
'placeholder' => 'Select...',
'url' => Url::to(['/publication/category'])
]
]); ?>
```

Отредактировал контроллер

```
public function actionCategory()
{

    $out = [];
    if (isset($_POST['depdrop_parents'])) {
        $parents = $_POST['depdrop_parents'];
        if ($parents != null) {
            $category_id = $parents[0];
            $out = $this->getCategoryTypeList($category_id);
            // the getSubCatList function will query the database based on the
            // cat_id and return an array like below:
            // [
            //    ['id'=>'<sub-cat-id-1>', 'name'=>'<sub-cat-name1>'],
            //    ['id'=>'<sub-cat_id_2>', 'name'=>'<sub-cat-name2>']
            // ]
            echo Json::encode(['output'=>$out, 'selected'=>'']);
            return;
        }
    }
    echo Json::encode(['output'=>'', 'selected'=>'']);

}

public function getCategoryTypeList($category_id)
{
        $modelName = '\common\models\category\type\PublicationRubricType';
        $query = call_user_func(array($modelName, 'find'));
        return $query->asArray()->all();
}
```

Здесь чисто тестовый метод getCategoryTypeList который не учитывает переданную переменную. Тем-не менее, он по идее должен работать. Результат - https://gyazo.com/fa58f18dcb22c402b09aff8ca05e32b2

Поле с типом категории доступно сразу, а значений там нет. Проверял-перепроверял id полей, url к действию. Все вроде правильно... Уже совсем голову поломал. Почему не работает? Что не так?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена. Похоже, я умудрился что-то сломать в *vendor* (хотя вроде-бы я ничего там вообще не трогал). Полностью удалил эту папку и переустановил с помощью `composer install`. Проблема решилась.